# Paypal Recurring Payments - Return url issue

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I need to include paypal recurring payments in my webapp for registration process.

1. I was able to create the "Subscription" button in the paypal portal and hadn't specified any return urls while creating the button. I had mentioned the amount as $0.2 and gave the payment cycles as 2 days (so 2 installments).
2. I got the html code and had included that code in the web-app and i had manually mentioned the return url, notifiy url in that html code as follows.
3. So, when the user tries to register for the first time (say it as first day) he will click paypal subscription button and pays the amount once the payment was success, we are able to redirect the user to success page and we are able to store the payment details in the database. For the first time it is working fine. Here compeltes the first installement.
4. So, for the second day,the recurring payment fires and amount is deducted. But the details are not updated in Database. So, how to handle this second time payments??

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)?  It will POST transaction data to a listener script you have on your server in real-time, so you can automate all sorts of things based on different transaction types.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I will be trying this IPN.Actually do we need to give both return url and notify url in the button html code manually or do we need to mention the return url while creating the button. As far as i see while creating button we can only give return URL. So, can you please help us out what would be good process to do?

Comment: You can add both return and notify_url in the button code.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. We had added both return url and notify_url in button code. But IPN returning invalid and also no parameters/variables returned by IPN. Do we need to do any configurations here??Can you please let us know what might be the issue??

Comment: Take a look at this article I wrote recently on [testing PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).  That should help you get to the bottom of whatever issue(s) you're having.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. We had did everything... but we see that our "notify_url" is getting called twice. We are updating our database in this notifiy url. here we are using ipn handler to get the parameters from the notify url and updating database. but notify url is being called 2 times. 1st time we get the transaction id and no amount and 2nd time we are getting amount and no transaction id. We feel this is strange. Can you please let us know incase if we are doing any thing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: The only reason it would be getting called 2 times is if you're setting the same URL for both your return URL and your notify URL, or if you've got an error happening causing PayPal's system to re-send because it did not get a 200 OK response back.

Comment: Hi Andrew.. Thanks for that... And generally what will be the transaction type for recurring payments. We need to test the IPN simulator...As we dont have any live environment to test the payment fail contditions, what type of parameters we can expect when payment is failed/denied. Please let us know. Thanks